# Show AngularJS parameter options in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, brackets

I have downloaded an editor called Brackets. It's great at helping me with AngularJS as you can see below.

My team uses PyCharm for developing. Is it possible to add this kinds of help to PyCharm?

[image]